# sed: bad option in substitution expression when using § as delimiter

Tags: sed

I was trying to use `§` (0xA7) as the delimiter for a sed command:

> ```
> sed -i'' 's§error_log = /var/log/php-fpm.log§error_log = /proc/self/fd/2§' /etc/php5/php-fpm.conf
> ```

I get:

> `sed: bad option in substitution expression`

or (on a different Linux system):

> `sed: -e expression #1, char 66: Unknown option to 's'`

If I change that to `@`:

> ```
> sed -i'' 's@error_log = /var/log/php-fpm.log@error_log = /proc/self/fd/2@' /etc/php5/php-fpm.conf
> ```

it works.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because AFAIK [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) expect an [ascii](/questions/tagged/ascii) character as delimiter, your char is unicode `U+A7` :

```
man ascii | grep A7
```

return **nothing**.

And like @steeldriver said in comment, `§` is encoded with two bytes, look :

```
$ od -c <<< §
0000000 302 247  \n
0000003
```

Comment: Thanks. The man page just talks about "characters", which I assumed to mean "any byte value between 0 and 255", maybe with the exceptions of 0 (zero), 10 (newline) and 92 (baskslash).

Comment: @AndreKR right - but `§` is likely encoded as *two* bytes

Comment: I typed it into a Dockerfile with an editor in CP1252 and I verified with a hex editor that it ends up in the file as 0xA7, which I assumed to be fine.